# Parameterised method returning generic class member in java

Tags: java, generics

Why is the following code not allowed?

```
class MyClass {
    List<? extends Something> list;
    <T extends Something> List<T> myFunc(T t) {
        list = new ArrayList<T>(); // ok
        list.add(t); // error
        return list; // error
    }
}
```

And how do you fix the code while maintaining the same? i.e. the class member `list` only accepts objects that is subclass of `Something` and the same for `myFunc()`?

Comment: I think you need to do that at the class level. That, or make `list` a local variable and use use `List<T> list` instead of `List<? extends Something> list`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the Generic `<T>` declaration can be done at class level.

This to my understanding is because the wildcard `?` cannot be used as a type argument.

> The wildcard is never used as a type argument for a generic method invocation, a generic class instance creation, or a supertype

So what I get is that Java will not know that `<T extends Something>` and the list that even when it has the context that extends the same, it cannot ensure that is of the same type.

A possible (probably not what you are looking for) solution will declare the Generic at class level.

It may work if we do a:

```
class Abc <T extends Something>{
    List<T> list;
    List<T> myFunc(T t) {
        list = new ArrayList<T>(); // ok
        list.add(t); 
        return list; 
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yea thanks. But I dont want to set the generic type early when declaring MyClass. The generic type is not known until myFunc() is called.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your `T` type parameter somewhere before you use it anywhere. Ideally you should define it with the class declaration. Because you have used it in many places inside the class. If `T` would have only used in a method scope, you can define it with the method signature.

You cannot modify the *Upper bounded* `<T extends Something>` and *Unbounded* `<?>` type instances.

It means, it is not allowed to add any elements to `List<?>` (Unbounded list) and `List<T extends Something>`.

If you want to get this to be working, you can use a lower bound type parameter for the List.

```
class MyClass<T super Something> {
    List<T super Something> list;
    <T super Something> List<T> myFunc(T t) {
        list = new ArrayList<T>(); // ok
        list.add(t); 
        return list; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I understand, thanks. I dont want to use `?` for list but I dont want to use untyped List list either. And there is no way to use List<T> list if T can only come from the method but not the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `list.add(t);` because `list` has type `List<? extends Something>` and `t` has type `T`, and there is no way to know whether `T` is a subtype of the unknown type that `?` represents.

Similarly, you can't do `return list;` because `list` has type `List<? extends Something>` and the return type of the list is `List<T>` and there is no way to know whether `List<? extends Something>` is `List<T>`.

I think what you're thinking is that you put a `List<T>` into the variable, so you know it's a `List<T>` and you try to use it like a `List<T>`. But that's not how it works. `list` has type `List<? extends Something>`. Whatever you may have put into it, that doesn't change the variable's type, and any uses of the variable must still be based on its compile-time type.

If you want to use the object that you created as a `List<T>` for things later in the method, you need to keep a variable of type `List<T>` to point to it, something like this:

```
<T extends Something> List<T> myFunc(T t) {
    List<T> tempList = new ArrayList<T>();
    list = tempList;
    tempList.add(t);
    return tempList;
}
```